# Login once for different WebApp, Possible?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, 2012

I have to multiple Web applications in the SP2013. For example, from the main site, http://mysite.com:80 , it has a link which links to another web in another web application, i.e. http://mysite.com:12345/Test . Now, when user accesses http://mysite.com:80 , it needs to login (no anonymous allowed), when user click link for http://mysite.com:12345/Test , it asks for login again although the credential is supposed to be the same.

Is there a way to get around this? so user only login once?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since the host name for each web application is different, the credentials are not passed along to the different sites.

The only way (I know of) for this to be possible would be that:

- The user is logged on windows on the same network as the site (for which the credentials can be passed from his windows account)
- The user is using Internet Explorer and has an option to pass current credentials to the different sites
- The same may be achievable on other browsers, if they allow for a similar configuration

http://expressionsinweb.com/2011/05/17/allow-the-pass-through-of-window%E2%80%99s-credentials-to-sharepoint/